# Finding unknown text from string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a listview in jQuery Mobile.  When the user swipes right, that entry is removed from my list.  All works good.
But when an item is added on to the list, I have a separate array which holds all the products I'm keeping:

`["Catalogue1/{value}"]`

when I remove the list item, how could I check for that value inside my array and remove it?

I have the html saved in a variable "product_li", inside that the value I'm looking to search for is stored in heading tags: `<h3 class="ui-li-heading">{Product-to-Remove}</h3>`

Is there a method or other way I can just search whats inside these heading tags?  Once I have that I know I can use .indexOf() to search for and remove it from my array, it's just getting the text from the larger string that I'm struggling with.

Comment: try this $('html:contains("search-text")').

Comment: @Sawyer05 Can include full `html` , arrays ?